# Is it possible to know the datatype of the column returned from Stored Proc records set from ado.net

Tags: stored-procedures, ado.net, c#-3.0

Is it possible to get the datatype of the column from the stored procedure in ado.net environment.

Suppose I have defined a table with say `name` and  `id`. Say name is having a datatype of varchar(20), and id is of type int.

Now from the ado.net prespective when I do a ExecuteReader, is it possible to know the datatypes of the columns?

Any sample/pseudo code or link will be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did anything like this, but ISTR that the ExecuteReader gives you a SQLDataReader object.  That object has a GetDataTypeName method that returns a string with the type of the column.